# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client nodejs , express

Tags: node.js, express

```
router.get("/user", async (req, res) => {
    console.log("user hit")
    try {
        const cook = req.cookies["jwt"]
        
        if(cook==null){
            return res.sendStatus(401).send({
                message: "unauthenticated"
            })
        }

        const claims = jwt.verify(cook, "secret")

        if (!claims) {
            return res.sendStatus(401).send({
                message: "unauthenticated"
            })

        };
        const userf = await LoginCred.findOne({ _id: claims._id });
        const { password, ...data } = await userf.toJSON();
        return res.send(data)

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return res.sendStatus(401).send({
            message: "unauthenticated"
        });
    }

})
```

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
im new to this is it because of async function

Answer (score 0):

You should change all your response calls like this

```
 return res.sendStatus(401).send({
      message: "unauthenticated"
 })
```

To this

```
 return res.status(401).send({
      message: "unauthenticated"
 })
```

".status( )" method only sets status for current response

".sendStatus()" method sets the status and sends response to the client

Your error usually means that you are trying to send the response once you've already sent it before. This can happen if:

1. you forgot to await data somewhere
2. you forgot to return from function after sending response
3. trying to send response multiple times in a row (like in your case)